# Boost.Qi compiler error with optional parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm a Boost.Qi beginner, so I'm trying some simple examples to try to get my mind around it. I'm trying to parse a string that looks like:

```
A:1     B:2           C:3
```

There is an arbitrary amount of whitespace between each component in the string. The `A:`, etc. portions are fixed, and I'd like to parse the integer values. The third component of the string, `C:3` in the above example, is optional. I came up with the following simple example to test Boost.Qi for this application:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string s = "A:1   B:2          C:3";

    int a, b;
    boost::optional<int> c;

    if (!qi::parse(s.begin(), s.end(),
        qi::lit("A:") >> qi::int_ >> +qi::space >> "B:" >> qi::int_ >> 
            -(+qi::space >> "C:" >> qi::int_), a, b, c))
    {
        std::cout << "failed to parse" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c.value_or(-1) << std::endl;
}
```

However, this fails to compile (using Boost v1.58 and g++ 5.4.0 in C++11 mode). In the typical sea of C++ template error messages, I find the following:

```
spirit.cc:15:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:130:12: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     struct container_value
```

and

```
spirit.cc:15:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:316:66: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::traits::container_value<int, void>’
             typedef typename traits::container_value<Attr>::type value_type;
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:329:15: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::traits::container_value<int, void>’
```

Is it obvious to anyone what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly [omit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/omit.html) both occurrences of `+qi::space`, since you're not interested in its attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original grammar looks like this (with some formatting):

```
   qi::lit("A:")
>> qi::int_
>> +qi::space
>> qi::lit("B:")
>> qi::int_
>> -(  +qi::space
    >> qi::lit("C:")
    >> qi::int_
    )
```

It's important to note the attribute types each of the terminals generates:

- [qi::lit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html) generates no attribute
- [qi::space](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html) generates a character attribute
- [qi::int](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/int.html) generates an int attribute

Furthermore, note the relevant rules for [compound attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html).

Based on that, you actually have:

- integer
- character vector (due to the [`+`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/plus.html))
- integer
- optional (due to the [`-`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/optional.html)) tuple (due to the [`>>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequence.html)) of

  - character vector (due to the [`+`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/plus.html))
  - integer

This does not match what you call `parse` with.

The key is to use the [`omit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/omit.html) directive to suppress the attributes you don't care about.

The correct grammar in that case would be:

```
   qi::lit("A:")
>> qi::int_
>> qi::omit[+qi::space]
>> qi::lit("B:")
>> qi::int_
>> -(  qi::omit[+qi::space]
    >> qi::lit("C:")
    >> qi::int_
    )
```

Comment: Excellent explanation; thanks. I mistakenly had thought that `qi::space` was one of the parser types that doesn't have an associated attribute (like `qi::lit`). Your answer makes it crystal clear.

Answer (score 4):

A way to fix this could be by using `phrase_parse` and `qi::space` skipper:

```
if (!qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(),
        qi::lit("A:") >> qi::int_ >> "B:" >> qi::int_ >> -("C:" >> qi::int_), qi::space, a, b, c))
```

Comment: This also works (and is actually a simpler implementation), so it's probably the way to go. I accepted the other answer because it gave a detailed explanation of why my example was wrong. Thanks for this input.

Comment: @JasonR Yes, I'd also say this would be the way to go, as you want to skip the spaces anyway.